# wont able to merge part-m-0000* by incremental lastmodified

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I first imported the table by

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.18/mysql --table mytable \    
--username raj --password root --target-dir /find1/1t -m 1
```

then i tried created a incremental lastmodified append job by using

```
sqoop job --create tasy \
-- import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.13/mysql --table mytable \
--username raj --password root --incremental lastmodified --append --check-
column lastUpdated --last-value "2017-11-05 02:43:43" --target-dir /find1/3t 
-m 1
```

and trigger the job by using

```
sqoop job --exec tasy
```

then i tried to merge the part file of in the new directory by using

```
sqoop merge --merge-key lastUpdated --new-data \
/find1/3t/part-m-0000* --onto /find1/1t --target-dir  \
/find5 --class-name mytable \
--jar-file /home/user/Desktop/mytable.jar
```

but every time it was throwing an error

[This was the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O44w.png)
[This is my table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyYgj.png)

When i use

```
sqoop merge --merge-key lastUpdated --new-data \
/find1/3t/part-m-00001 --onto /find1/1t --target-dir  \
/find5 --class-name mytable \
--jar-file /home/user/Desktop/mytable.jar
```

it works but I need to merge all the part file

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: Suppose in directory /find1/3t/part-m-00000 to part-m-00010 files I need to merge with the file in /find1/1t /part-m-00000 in any dir @0TTT0

Answer (score 0):

Proving path like `/find1/3t/part-m-0000*` is not correct. Please specify directory path `/find1/3t/` instead of providing filename.